# Emacs: Complete base class methods for Python

Tags: python, emacs, emacs-jedi

Is it possible to make either `jedi.el` or `anaconda-mode` complete base class methods? For example, when subclassing `html.parser.HTMLParser` I expect it to complete the following code at point `(1)` (base class has methods like `handle_data` or `handle_starttag`):

```
import html.parser
class MyParser(html.parser.HTMLParser):
    def handle_  # (1)
```

Comment: You might consider asking on the [emacs.se] site.  (It's not completely off-topic here, as you're asking about programming modes rather than general editing, but it might widen the available pool of experts).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've done some research on this issue and I've found that it is implemented in the latest version of jedi (0.10.0). Unfortunately, this version is in development state right now and is not available from pip. However, many editors use 0.10.0: Atom, VsCode, and even jedi-vim from the author of jedi.

It's easy to update jedi's version in anaconda-mode: https://github.com/nightuser/anaconda-mode. The actual change is just a one line. The Python part of anaconda-mode must be reinstalled -- simply delete `anaconda-mode` directory. The default location is `~/.emacs.d/anaconda-mode` for Emacs and `~/.emacs.d/.cache/anaconda-mode` for Spacemacs.

**upd:** It seems that 0.10.0 will be released soon: https://github.com/davidhalter/jedi/issues/740 .

**upd2:** It was released and know everything works out of the box. Just remove `anaconda-mode` directory and it'll automatically install latest version.